# Different type returned by getter than type of field in Jackson. How to convert map to set?

Tags: java, jackson

Classes:

```
public class Contact implements ContactInterface {
    private Set<ContactInfoInterface> contactInfo;

    public Map<String, ContactInfo> getContactInfo() {
        // create maps from contactInfo set
        return map;
    }
    //no setter
}

public class ContactInfo implements ContactInfoInterface {
    private String contactInfoValue;

    public String getContactInfoValue {
        return this.contactInfoValue;
    }
    public void setContactInfoValue(String value) {
        this.contactInfoValue = value;
    }
}
```

Jackson MixIn:

```
public abstract class ContactMixIn implements ContactInterface {

    @JsonProperty
    public abstract Map<String, ContactInfo> getContactInfo();
}
```

I have problem with deserializing json created by Jackson. In result of serialization I got json in which I have a contactInfo as a map (which is basically what we have as a returned type in getter). But when I deserialize it then Jackson is trying to instantiate contactInfo as a set (which is also true cause contactInfo is a set). But of course Jackson can't map the json value to set and strange exception occurs. So my question is how can I deserialize the map in that case to get the set of ContactInfoInterface?

They are not third part classes so I can add setter or anything else to them. But if there is an option I would rather not do that.

Thanks for help

Comment: I wonder if the simplest way will be adding new basic getter for a contactInfo set: public Set<ContactInfoInterface> getContactInfo(){} but don't add it to ContactInterface and then Change ContactMixIn to extends Contact class instead of implementing ContactInterface. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to convert a `Set` to a `Map`.  `Set` is an extension of `Collection`, `Map` is an entirely different object.  If `ContactInfoInterface` contains the information you need to **manually build** a `Map` you could do that.  But trying to pass back a `Set` in the form of a `Map` will never work.

Comment: I don't think so you understand me OK. Of course I create map from set manually and a getter method returned that map and then it is convert to json. And during deserializing Jackson is trying to put what he has in json to a set. And I wonder how I can serialize and deserialize Contact instance to have set of ContactInfo properly instantiated.

Comment: Serialization, if I recall correctly, knows what the types of the private fields are.  This would mean you need a getter and setter that corresponds to the actual type of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question: but if it helps, keep in mind that the type Jackson expects does NOT need to be same for serialization and deserialization. But names associated must match for particular use case.
It would be helpful to see JSON you would expect to use.

So: when serializing things, what Jackson looks are:

- Getters: if one exists for specific name (either from Bean naming convention, like `getName()` -> `name`; or from `@JsonProperty`), it will be used to get value, using return type
- Fields: if no getter exists, and field is either public OR matches a visible setter (public, or annotated with `@JsonProperty`), it will be used. Type will be type of field.

for deserialization, it will be instead:

- Setters: similar to getters with respect to finding name of property; type will be type of the first argument.
- Field: if no setter exists, field is used, if visible (same rules as above, except can be "pulled in" by getter.

Since field only has one type, you need to use combination of getter and setter (or getter+field, or setter+field) so that types Jackson uses differ.

In addition, if you really only want one property, and other things are only needed for conversion, you may need to use `@JsonIgnore` to hide specific property or accessors.
You can even use "split" annotations, where, say, getter has `@JsonProperty` (so it WILL be used), but setter and field have `@JsonIgnore`.